# How to utilize xapi or scorm content packages

Tags: scorm, scorm2004, tin-can-api, lms, xapi

I am coding an LMS. Backend and UI is almost ready. Our first intention was to code our own content studio but using existing studios are way quicker. We want to use rise and rise gives the following exports:

[image]

[This](https://github.com/isaturk66/lmsexport/) is a github repo of xapi and scorm 2004 exports. As you can see, index.html (scormcontent/index.html in scorm2004) is working perfectly. UI is intact and it is saving progression value internally.

My question is how can I get that data and save it to my own database (I know how to use a database, I just cant get the data stream from scorm).

After I save those values to my database, I also need to insert them back into the scorm or xapi when the user opens website.

If you guys can just show me how to retrieve that data, I can do everything from there. I read something about an endpoint??

Note: Functions at the bottom of index.html such as finishQuiz() are not working, at least I couldnt make them work.

Another Note: I really don't want iframe please

Answer (score 0):

See my answer to [Get the scorm values from the LMS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68955409/get-the-scorm-values-from-the-lms)

SCORM is a set of standards defining not only APIs for communication but also structures for packaging learning content. You will need to implement one of the SCORM APIs (SCORM 1.2 is probably easiest if you want to support most authoring tools and don't need any of the advanced sequencing features of SCORM 2004) or xAPI.

If you are going to implement xAPI you will want to look into how to implement it as an "LRS" (i.e. the server that consumes xAPI data from a learning activity) as xAPI doesn't normally refer to LMSes. Since you will also want to serve the content rather than just consume the data they generate, you might want to opt to implement cmi5, which builds on xAPI to also define a packaging format to replace SCORM.