# Get the scorm values from the LMS

Tags: javascript, symfony4, scorm2004

I created a LMS in symfony, I want to implement the scorm standard on it. Has anyone already done a project on it? I wanted to know how to get the scorm values from the LMS and how to connect them.
Thank you.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

SCORM 2004 is defined in a set of ebooks colloquially referred to as the "SCORM bookshelf". You can find these on the ADL SCORM website: https://www.adlnet.gov/projects/scorm/

For 2004 there are three books you'll need to implement:

- The CAM book defines the format of the `imsmanifest.xml` manifest file you'll find inside the zip file (in SCORM called a "PIF") that contains the SCORM module.
- The RTE book defines the Run Time Environment, i.e. the JavaScript API a SCORM 2004 module will try to find and talk to.
- The SN book defines the sequencing logic (i.e. what happens if you want to navigate between different activities) as well as how objectives are handled on the LMS side.

Implementing SCORM 2004 is not an easy task. For a sense of scale: depending on how thorough you are, for an experienced solo developer working full time just on this I would estimate an implementation time of at least a month, more with proper compliance testing.

Most LMSes still only support SCORM 1.2 and limit their SCORM 2004 "support" to the bare necessities to run a module with no regard for the actual sequencing logic, which takes the bulk of the implementation effort. Also note that SCORM 2004 is incompatible with SCORM 1.2 so if you want to support both you will need to implement both, or at least provide API wrappers for both versions. The SCORM 1.2 bookshelf only contains the RTE and CAM books but also includes a third book containing corrections and clarifications.

Also note that work on the SCORM series of standards has ceased with the last, 4th edition of SCORM 2004 dating back to 2009. The ADL has since blessed the Experience API (xAPI, initially known as "TinCan") standard, which is more general purpose, and the cmi5 packaging standard which builds on xAPI as an alternative to SCORM: https://xapi.com/